# Help with using Caml in rest api calls - filtering doesn't work for me

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, calculated-column, caml-query

I'm trying to filter a Posts list(Blog) by month and year.
I created a calculated column and used the Published Date to extract month and year.
But my below code doesn't filter correctly when i use rest api and caml below.

**I am supposed to be returning no data or 1 item but its returning all items**

I have tried all i can but no luck.

Not sure what i'm missing.

Thanks in advance

```
function restCallwithCaml(_urlblog,listName) {

// var caml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='PublishedMonth'/><Value Type='Number'>11</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";  

     var caml ="<View>" +
               "<Query>" +
                   "<Where>" +
                      "<And>" +
                         "<And>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                               "<FieldRef Name='PublishedYear' />" +
                               "<Value Type='Number'>2019</Value>" +
                            "</Eq>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                               "<FieldRef Name='PublishedMonth'/>" +
                               "<Value Type='Number'>11</Value>" +
                            "</Eq>" +
                         "</And>" +
                         "<Contains>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='PostCategory'/>" +
                            "<Value Type='LookupMulti'>Events</Value>" +
                         "</Contains>" +
                      "</And>" +
                   "</Where>" +
                "</Query>"
                "</View>";

    /// set request data  
    var data = { "query" :{"__metadata": { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }, "ViewXml": caml}};  

    /// make an ajax call  
    $.ajax({  
       url: _urlblog + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+ listName +"')/items",  
            method: "POST",  
            data: data,  
            headers: {  
               "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
               'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',  
               'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'  
            },  
            success: function (data) {  
            ///do your code  

            console.log(data.d.results);

            },  
            error: function (data) {  
            ///do your code  
           }  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your code snippet for query having **contains** with **eq** and think will resolve your your problem.
As when filtering with multilookup column it is advised to use Eq instead of contains.
[For reference](https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/multi-lookup-fields-in-caml-queries-eq-vs-contains/)

**Update**

Also update the endpoint with

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+ listName +"')/GetItems
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil for the quick reply but even if use this simple query :- var caml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='PublishedMonth'/><Value Type='Number'>11</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"; 
it doesn't work

Comment: can you share your data list view for better understanding

Comment: What do you mean? If i'm using rest this would be my URL:  _api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Posts')/items?$select=id,Title,News_x0020_Images,PublishedDate,Byline. As i said its a OTB Posts list

Comment: Sunil ..I changed the contains to eq and changed items to GetItems and nothing worked.

Comment: got it and it works changed these three things 
type: "POST"  
data: JSON.stringify(data),  
and from Value Type='Number'  to Type=Calculated

Comment: But it seems the cam query isn't work- its not filtering ad it should be. Any ideas what i'm missing?